# Iterate over matrices in Octave

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, octave

I need to perform the same operation on several matrices, so I'd like to write a `for` loop with, say, variable `i` where at each iteration, `i` has the value of one of my matrices.

Is that even possible in Octave?

For clarification: I do not want to iterate over elements of a matrix, but over a list of matrices.

Comment: Depending on the operation you have to do on each matrix, you could vectorize it and thus avoid the loop

Comment: @LuisMendo If at all possible yes, but I'd like to do things such as remove the first column of each matrix, where the matrixes have different sizes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a 3d matrix, where each "layer" represent a 2d matrix, say:

```
A = rand(3,3,3);
for ii = 1:3
     A(:, :, ii) %something
end
```

Or you could have cells, where each `A{ii}` is a 2d array, and you can use a loop in a normal way.

```
for ii = 1:3
    A{ii} % something
end
```

Comment: That's a pretty good idea! but I was rather thinking of matrixes that have different dimensions. For example, say I want to remove the first column of each of my matrixes, all of them with different sizes

Comment: @Miquel: Then you should use the last approach. `A{1} = rand(4); A{2} = rand(5)` works fine =)

Comment: Ah! There we go; Cells is what I was missing. Couldn't call them lists, could they? :) Thanks a bunch. Also, here's some more info for anyone reading this in the future: [Cell Arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Basic-Usage-of-Cell-Arrays.html#Basic-Usage-of-Cell-Arrays)